# Angular Conditional (click) event is not working with Multiple execution

Tags: angular

I am trying to achieve something like this in one my project.

```
<div (click)="condition && myCustomeFunction1(); myCustomeFunction2();">Action</div>
```

Above code only applies on first execution ie. `myCustomerFunction1();`

**Note** I have a limation to not use [disable] to prevent click. So,
kindly suggest other possibilities.

Comment: Try use parenthesis: `(click)="(condition && var1 = true); var2 = true;"` or `(click)="condition && (var1 = true; var2 = true;)"` according you want

Comment: This seems to be working for me [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qynnbm), can you please reproduce the problem in stackblitz? and update the question

Comment: @Eliseo, It's not working, check with false condition, both exectution should not perform.

Comment: `(click)="condition && var1 = true; condition && var2 = true;"` ?

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks your solution seems to be working, small update in question, instead of multiple variable, I changed it to multiple different function.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is seems to be working.

```
(click)="condition && myCustomeFunction1(); condition && myCustomeFunction2();"
```